# Using docker image with database or LocalDB for integration tests in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I'm currently investigating how to best implement integration tests. We use C# to build Azure Functions and have unit-tests in-place (runs as part of the build in Azure DevOps).

Next step is to include integration tests for integrating with MS SQL Server (we use Dapper). I have done some research and concluded that using an in-memory database is not the way to go (different engine).
Therefore I'm wondering if it is possible to create a Docker image with a SQL Server or instantiate LocalDB(https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md does not list SQL Server Express or LocalDB), run scripts against it (to setup the database to the desired state) and then run integration tests (using MSTest)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so sqllocaldb.exe is installed on the VS2017 build agents. I ended up using (and improving) https://github.com/ritterim/automation-sql to wrap sqlocaldb.exe in C#.